# Send dropzone with call function

Tags: javascript, php, request, dropzone.js, dropzone

My problem is that I must combine a normal form with dropzone.js for a drag&drop upload. After the user clicks the submit-button, then a ajax-request send the data to a php-script if there are values in the inputs.

But my original form call onSave function to validate inputs datas. If I send the form with the code below, POST method send datas perfectly, but onSave is not called. So nothing happened.

How can I modify the code to call onSave too, after upload a files?

```
<?php

function onSave(){
    //validate and save to database
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="item/create" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-request="onSave" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="mydropzone">
    //inputs

    <div id="dropzonePreview" class="dropzone dropzonePreview">
        <div class="dz-default dz-message"><button class="dz-button" type="button">Drop files here to upload</button></div>
    </div>

    //more inputs
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save">Send</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$( document ).ready(function () {

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $("#mydropzone").dropzone({ 

        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        previewsContainer: '#dropzonePreview',
        clickable: false,

        accept: function(file, done) {
            console.log("uploaded");
            done();
        },
        error: function(file, msg){
            alert(msg);
        },

        // The setting up of the dropzone
        init: function() {
            var myDropzone = this;

            this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                myDropzone.processQueue();
                //it's send form, but not call onSave function
            });

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call `onSave()` function?

```
init: function() {
            var myDropzone = this;

            this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                myDropzone.processQueue();
                //it's send form, but not call onSave function
              <?php  onSave();  ?> // <----
            });
```

Comment: But onSave is a php function.

Answer (score 0):

It was my solution, I hope help you.

```js
// First: Create your event
const myEvent = new Event("saveImages");

// Second: Call your funcion,
function callDropzone(){
    $("#myDropzone").dropzone({
        url: "YOUR_URL",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        init: function() {
            myDropzone = this;
            // Here is listened your event
            window.addEventListener("saveImages",function(event){
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            });
        }
    });
}

// Third: Distpach your event, where and when you want.
window.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

```html
<!-- Dropzone container -->
<div id="myDropzone" class="dropzone"></div>
```